# How do I get alternate style sheets to work on iOS5 Safari?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, mobile-safari, ios5

I have been working on a HTML5 app for the iPad. Part of the app includes using alternative style sheets. This worked great on iOS 4 Safari and works fine on Safari on my desktop. However, I just upgraded one of our iPads to iOS 5 beta and it no longer works. Any ideas?

Here is my code for this.

```
function (options) {
    var i, a, main;
    for (i = 0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
        if (a.rel.indexOf("style") != -1
        && a.title) {
            a.disabled = true;
            if (a.title == options.title) {
                a.disabled = false;
                console.log('The theme should be changing to : ' + a.title);                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is 'a.rel.style' supposed to do? a.rel is a string if I am not mistaken. So string.style is incorrect.

Comment: Actually no, "a" is a link like this <link href=​"lib/​touch/​resources/​css/​illinois.css" rel=​"alternative stylesheet" type=​"text/​css" title=​"illinois" disabled> so a.rel.style returns "alternative stylesheet" or stylesheet if it is actually a style sheet and null if not. So that is checking to see if the link is actually a stylesheet.

Comment: according to the specs found on the MDC the rel attribute of a HTMLLinkElement is a DOMString. So the .style part doesn't do anything and is probably causing safari to just bail out. 
Just use a.rel.indexOf('stylesheet')!=-1

Comment: ahh... you are absolutely right on that one.... however, that doesn't appear to be what was failing on me because a.rel.style was returning "undefined" not -1. I will change that though. My code does work in safari on the desktop and iOS4 it is only on iOS 5 that I am having the problem.

Comment: Does the message appear in the console?

Comment: Yes, the message did appear in the console.

Comment: What happens if you move the a.disabled=true into the else. So if(...){a.disabled=false;...}else{a.disabled=true;}

Answer (score 0):

After searching SO and the web, I was not happy with any of the solutions.  So I came up with a new solution which is working in chrome, ff, ie and safari and safari on an old ipad:

First set styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"              href="./codebase/touchui.css"       data-title="default"        type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"    href="./codebase/ios.css"           data-title="ios"                type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"    href="./codebase/jq.css"            data-title="jq"                 type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"    href="./codebase/sky.css"           data-title="sky"                type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet"    href="./codebase/green.css"         data-title="green"          type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
```

Notice the attribute "data-title" this is a user-defined attribute.

Then use this function to change the style sheet, (note that I have it set in the app scope, you can make it a standard function:

```
app = {}

app.styleSet=function(title) {
  var i, a
  var o;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) 
    if (a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute('data-title') ) {
      if (a.getAttribute('data-title') == title) 
        o = a

      a.setAttribute("rel", "alternate stylesheet"); 
      a.setAttribute("title", a.getAttribute('data-title'));
      a.disabled = true
  }

  o.setAttribute("title", undefined); 
  o.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"); 
  o.disabled = false
  //app.cookieCreate("style", title, 365);
}
```